# How to encapsulate a Material Design md-grid-tile element in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm trying to refactor my tiles by creating a directive that replaces:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols="2" md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="12px">
  <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="card in cards" class="card-tile" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
          <h3>{{CCtrl.card.title}}</h3>
          <h4 class="md-caption">Last updated {{CCtrl.card.lastUpdated | ago}}</h4>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

with a custom directive:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols="2" md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="12px">
  <card ng-repeat="card in cards" card="card"></card>
</md-grid-list>
```

with the below definition:

```
  .directive('card', function(CONFIG) {
      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          scope: {
              card: '='
          },
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: './ng/Card/card.tpl.html',
          controller: 'CardCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'CCtrl',
          bindToController: true
      }
  })
```

and template (card.tpl.html):

```
  <md-grid-tile class="card-tile" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
          <h3>{{CCtrl.card.title}}</h3>
          <h4 class="md-caption">Last updated {{CCtrl.card.lastUpdated | ago}}</h4>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
  </md-grid-tile>
```

I must use "replace: true" for Material Design styles/layout to work. 
I am getting the below error:

```
Error: $compile:multidir
Multiple Directive Resource Contention
Multiple directives [card (module: project), mdGridTile (module: 
material.components.gridList)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <md-
grid-tile class="card-tile" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1" ng-
repeat="card in cards.sketchCards" card="card">
```

Is there a way to encapsulate md-grid-tile in a custom directive?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `scope` property from your `card` directive we can take away the isolated scope of that directive

Then in the `link` function for the `card` directive we can [$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) the card attribute and store it on the scope or controller.

```
function link (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    // we do this to bypass isolated scope
    // stored on scope
    scope.card = scope.$eval(attrs.card);
    // stored on controller
    ctrl.card = scope.$eval(attrs.card);
}
```

The downside to this approach is you may have to `$watch` for the card data to exist in the `card` controller.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Removing the scope and having to actively watch variables makes working with data more difficult. Not sure I want to do this. The reason to refactor is to make the code simpler. I am wondering if I am missing something obvious.